# Is it possible to add Quasar UMD to an existing project without loading Vue via CDN?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, quasar-framework

Is it possible to add Quasar UMD to an existing project without loading Vue via CDN?

I already have Vue installed via npm and just want to use a few Quasar components. Is it possible to just add Quasar components and not load vue via CDN. When I follow the UMD docs it says to add both

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^2.0.0/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.22.10/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>
```

and if I remove the Vue CDN it gives me this error:

```
quasar.umd.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')
    at quasar.umd.min.js:6:24336
    at quasar.umd.min.js:6:177
    at quasar.umd.min.js:6:186
```

Comment: This may help you [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/)